# How to make a button respond visually before a new Activity is opend?

Tags: android, animation, button, android-activity

I am working with Android Studio. I have a button, when I cklick the button a new Activity is being opend. The whole thing should be animated nicely there for the button shall be animated before I open the new Activity. I many Google apps when you click on a button the button seems to grow into the following page. I want to build something close to this. I want my button to "grow" and while it is still growing I want my Activity to fade in. I know how to open a new Activity on button click and how to animate things.

Until now I have this:

```
public void onButtonClick(View view){
View button = view.findById(R.id.mybutton);
button.animate().scaleX(2).scaleY(2).setDuration(1000);
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.abc_fade_in, R.anim.abc_fade_out);
}
```

This kind of works but when I click back to my old Activity the button is still big , what is logically. But when I add an animation to get it back to it´s size the whole thing doesn´t work or the button is animated when I go back.But I don´t want to see the button getting smaller.
I also would like to know if this is the proper way to to what I intend to do. To my this seems like a usual thing to do yet I found very little on this topic. Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use animation listener and when particular animation ends you can do your work.

```
animationObject.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener(){

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        // Start your new activity here.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }
});
```

Comment: but when should I make the button small again...+I want the button to still grow when the Activity is floating in.

Comment: You can run another animation which makes your button smaller back to it's original size after the first animation finishes and your open your activity.

Comment: but then I would see the button getting smaller

Comment: You need to set duration to 200ms of second animation. so that when you come back from the second activity animation already been finished.

Comment: But you can´t animate something in an not focused Activity